# Fill multiple columns in excel with data from other sheets with one formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

Excel newbie here. I have 3 excel sheets.
Sheet 1 contains data in columns A and B, sheet 2 contains data in column A.

What I'm trying to do is enter a formula in sheet 3 such that columns A, B and C contain the data of sheet1!A, sheet1!B and sheet2!A respectively.

If I use:

```
C1 =sheet1!A1:B1;sheet2!A1
```

I get an "#VALUE!" in cell C1, instead of values in columns A, B and C.

I found another answer which suggested using an array somewhere. I got a bit further with that. Using:

```
{=sheet1!A1:B1}
```

correctly filled in column A and B of sheet 3. However, once I add in the data from the second sheet, I get an error saying that the shape does not match. I was trying it like this:

```
{sheet1!A1:B1;sheet2!A1}
```

Am I missing an easy way to accomplish what I want to do? I'm trying to do it with a formula in column A of sheet 3 since I have to do this for a lot of rows, and referencing each column seperately takes a lot of work.

Comment: `Sheet3!A1=CHOOSE(COLUMN(),Sheet1!$A1,Sheet1!$B1,Sheet2!$A1)`

Comment: This only seems to fill in column A of sheet 3.

Comment: Insert this formula to A1. Drag this selection till C1. Drag triple cells selection down as far as you need.

Comment: the requirement to enter a formula once doesn't make sense to begin with. On Sheet3 make `A1` `=sheet1!A1`, `B1` `=sheet1!B1` and `C1` `=sheet2!A1` and drag all three down. Coercing a formula into doing this for you doesn't actually even save keystrokes. It's lunacy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried CONCATENATE()?

Try putting this formula in Cell A1 on Sheet 3 and then dragging the formula down as far as you need.

```
=CONCATENATE(Sheet1!A1," ",Sheet1!B1," ",Sheet2!A1)
```

If you don't want the spaces, use this instead:

```
=CONCATENATE(Sheet1!A1,Sheet1!B1,Sheet2!A1)
```